# PHP regex, tags occur multiple times in a string

Tags: php, regex

My goal is to bold what is in between tags {{ }}. The problem is that if tags occur multiple times it does not work the way I want.

```
$string1 = "hello my {{name}} is bo.";
$string2 = "hello my {{name}} is bo. Or {{not}}";
$startPoint = '{{';
$endPoint = '}}';
$result = preg_replace('/('.preg_quote($startPoint).')(.*)('.preg_quote($endPoint).')/si', '<b>$2</b>', $string);
```

Result with string1: (as it should)

hello my **name** is bo.

Result with string2: (not as I want)

hello my **name}} is bo. Or {{not**

I feel that there is something silly I'm missing, just not sure what. All help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thank you! (.*?) worked as charm, if you write answer I'll mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: `.*` is a GREEDY match. it'll suck up everything between the very first `{{` and the very LAST `}}`. Try `.*?`, which is non-greedy

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
$pattern = "~{{([^}{]*)}}~";
$replacement = "<b>$1</b>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

`.*` would does a greedy match. That is it eats up everything between the first `{{` and the last `}}` braces. To do a shortest possible match, you need to add a quantifier `?` just after to `*`. All the matched characters are stored into the first group because of the presence of capturing group in your pattern ,ie, `(.*)`. That's why you get the string `name}} is bo. Or {{not` into group 1.

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `{{` Matches the two opening curly braces.
- `([^}{]*)` Matches and captures any charcter zero or more times but not of `}` or `{`
- `}}` Matches the two closing curly braces.

Comment: +1, but maybe you could add an explanation of what the OP did wrong